# Nginx + Capistrano + ruby project server error .rvm/ruby-2.3.1-p112/ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, sinatra, capistrano

My settings capistrano:

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'

# If you are using rvm add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rvm'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.1-p112'
#Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**Deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'app-name'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user/app-name.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/app-name'

#set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{ log }

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

**deploy/production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production

server '46.101.214.91', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

When i try to run my server i get the following error(logs from nginx):

```
App 3789 stderr: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1-p112/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
[ 2016-12-01 09:32:54.4141 3762/7f9524f98700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/sudoku/$
  Error ID: 355ab1fd
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-m06d8H.html
```

Info about RVM:

```
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01:~$ rvm info

ruby-2.3.1:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01 4.4.0-47-generic #68~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:42:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/14.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 day 1 hour 19 minutes 39 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/deploy/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.3.1p112"
    date:         "2016-04-26"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2016-04-26 revision 54768"
    full_version: "ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1"
    ruby:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1"
    IRBRC:        "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

On remote server i installed rvm with ruby version 2.3.1. Can`t undestand what wrong? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Have you confirmed the path does in fact exist? (`/home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1-p112/ruby`)

Comment: ```cd /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1-p112/
-bash: cd: /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1-p112/: No such file or directory```  i checked, no. but why find in this path?

Comment: what is the output of `rvm info`?

Comment: i added in body of question

Comment: please help....

Comment: Hmm.. it's difficult to say without being able to debug it myself. Doesn't look like the patch is installed (p112) which is in the path. What about if you set the ruby version in your `Capfile` - `set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.1'`?

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past and just had to power through it. Keep searching google/stackoverflow and try different configuration options in both capistrano and rvm on the system until you figure out how it should all fit together. It's a bit of a pain.